# Sales Summary Report Square connect

Tags: square-connect

Is it possible to generate a daily sales summary report using square-connect? I see where I can list items, categories etc, but nothing where I could generate a daily sales summary report.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Connect API to retrieve a list of your daily sales and see which items were purchased in each of those sales.

### Retrieving daily sales

You retrieve a list of your daily sales with the [List Payments](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#get-payments) endpoint. Each [`Payment`](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#datatype-payment) object returned includes a breakdown of the money collected (taxes, tip, etc.) and the form of tender used (credit card, cash, etc.).

By default, this endpoint returns a list of *all* of the payments you've ever processed, but you can specify a custom time window with the `begin_time` and `end_time` parameters.

For example, to retrieve all of your payments for 21 April 2014:

- `begin_time` is `2014-04-21T00:00:00-07:00`
- `end_time` is `2014-04-22T00:00:00-07:00`

The `-07:00` offset assumes you're on Pacific Daylight Time (PDT); be sure to modify this offset for your time zone.

The full URL of your request to the List Payments endpoint is then:

`https://connect.squareup.com/v1/me/payments?begin_time=2014-04-21T00%3A00%3A00-07%3A00&end_time=2014-04-22T00%3A00%3A00-07%3A00`

Note that the values for `begin_time` and `end_time` are URL-escaped to prevent errors.

### Determining items sold

Once you have your list of daily payments, provide the `id` of each `Payment` object to the [Retrieve Payment](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#get-paymentid) endpoint. This endpoint returns a `Payment` object that includes one additional field: `itemizations`.

This array of [`PaymentItemization`](https://connect.squareup.com/docs/api?path=connect#datatype-paymentitemization) objects describes the items included in the payment. The `item_detail` field of each `PaymentItemization` includes handy information like the item's `item_id` and `category_name` (if any). You can use this information to analyze which types of items you're selling when.

Here's an excerpt from a sample `PaymentItemization` object:

```
{
  "name": "Donut",
  "quantity": 12,
  "item_detail": {
    "category_name": "Pastries",
    "sku": "1234",
    "item_id": "442d1344-6d2b-4238-83d0-0284dfd335d8",
    "variation_id": "cb890728-cfdc-4690-9e03-349f964f756r"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: OK, but what I am looking for in the report is how many items in each category was sold. I am looking to use Square in a deli. I would have categories Lrg, Sm, Wraps, Drinks, Deserts etc. Right now Square doe not offer a report that would list how many of each category was sold. I am looking to see if there is in API to get that info.

Comment: Thanks for the followup information. I've expanded the answer to describe how to get item information associated with each payment. You can use this information to analyze the frequency with which items in different categories are purchased.

Comment: FWIW I've been playing with this API and I don't think you need to do a separate Retrieve Payment request. The List Payments endpoint returns the Payment objects in addition to the IDs of each transaction.